# Extra Artifact published when using templates

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, azure-rm-template

Currently started using global templates in the majority of my pipelines and there is an issue occurring where an empty artifact is getting published in addition to the original artifact.

This is causing minor issues with some of my deployment groups (workaround is to just ignore it when downloading). While it is not causing major issues, I'm just curious about why the extra file is being published as well as preventing it.

[image: Published Artifact]

EDIT:

Included my yaml template being used as:

```
parameters:
  ArtifactPath: ''
  ArtifactName: ''
  ArtifactPublish: false
  Artifacts: []
  Solution: '**/*.sln'

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build, Pack, and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  variables:
    solution: ${{ parameters.Solution }}
    buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    prereleaseVersion: '$(majorVersion).$(minorVersion).$(Build.BuildNumber)-$(Build.SourceBranchName)'
    releaseVersion: '$(majorVersion).$(minorVersion).$(Build.BuildNumber)'
  steps:
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    displayName: "Install Nuget Tool"
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'Restore Nuget Packages'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      vstsFeed: 'FEED'
  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build Solution'
    inputs:
      solution: '$(solution)'
      msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
  - task: VSTest@2
    displayName: 'Run Unit Tests'
    inputs:
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'Pack Prerelease Nuget Packages'
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'))
    inputs:
      command: 'pack'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      packagesToPack: '**/nuspec/*.nuspec'
      versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
      versionEnvVar: prereleaseVersion
      verbosityPack: 'detailed'
  - task: NuGetCommand@2 
    displayName: 'Push Prerelease Nuget Packages'
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'))
    inputs:
      command: 'push'
      packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg'
      nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
      publishVstsFeed: 'FEED'
      verbosityPush: 'normal'
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'Pack Release Nuget Packages'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'))
    inputs:
      command: 'pack'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      packagesToPack: '**/nuspec/*.nuspec'
      versioningScheme: 'byEnvVar'
      versionEnvVar: releaseVersion
      verbosityPack: 'detailed'
  - task: NuGetCommand@2 
    displayName: 'Push Release Nuget Packages'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'))
    continueOnError: true
    inputs:
      command: 'push'
      packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg'
      nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
      publishVstsFeed: 'FEED'
      verbosityPush: 'detailed'
  - task: PublishSymbols@2
    displayName: 'Publish Symbols to Symbol Server'
    inputs:
      SearchPattern: '**/bin/**/*.pdb'
      SymbolServerType: 'TeamServices'
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.ArtifactPublish, true) }}:
    - ${{ each artifact in parameters.Artifacts }}:
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        displayName: 'Copy .artifactignore: ${{ artifact.ArtifactPath }}'
        inputs:
          SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
          Contents: '.artifactignore'
          TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{ artifact.ArtifactPath }}'
    - ${{ each artifact in parameters.Artifacts }}:
      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        displayName: 'Publish Artifact: ${{ artifact.ArtifactName }}'
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/${{ artifact.ArtifactPath }}'
          artifactName: '${{ artifact.ArtifactName }}'
```

Yaml file that consumes it:

```
trigger:
  - release
  - development
  - master
  - feature/*
  - task/*

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      name: Project/Repo-Name
      type: git
      ref: refs/heads/release
  
variables:
  # This is the version displayed in package manager (Major.Minor.BuildNumber)
  majorVersion: 1
  minorVersion: 1
  
jobs:
- template: Templates/build.yml@templates
  parameters:
    Solution: 'SolutionName'
    ArtifactPublish: true
    Artifacts:
    - ArtifactPath: 'bin/directory/$(buildConfiguration)'
      ArtifactName: 'ArtifactName'
```

Comment: It's difficult for us to  locate the cause of the issue with info above. Could you please share some details about how your azure-pipelines.yml and templates.yml look like, so that we can check for you directly?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't get any notifications when you updated the question with the details. It's recommended to comment `@somebody` to let him know if there's any update :)

Comment: I just found the cause of your issue with the help of your updated details, please check it and feel free to let me know if it helps to resolve your puzzle/issue.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue?

Comment: It looks like you were right and this is expected. I was worried about extra stuff sneaking into my release pipeline but turns out this doesn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one [Publish Symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=azure-devops) task in your template, this task will publish symbols to the symbol server in Azure Artifacts with a random name. That's why we can see the extra artifact in `Published` tab, it's **expected behavior** when using `PublishSymbols@2` task.

[image]

> I'm just curious about why the extra file is being published as well
> as preventing it.

It's **not recommended** to disable or remove the `Publish Symbols` step though it helps to remove the artifact. This task is quite important for some scenarios where you want to have the ability to debug the published nuget packages, check my [another similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60993769/unable-to-stepinto-nuget-library-with-symbols-loaded/61006017#61006017). So my suggestion is just ignoring it~